# Detect font size in pixels using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I detect font size using jQuery? If I am using `em` and i need to detect font size in pixels

```
<h1 style="font-size: 5em">Size of font in pixels?</h1>
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more detail about what you have tried and the reasons why you want to do this?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/g9uKq/

I made you a fiddle just to be clear.

```
var size = $("h1").css('font-size');
```

Answer (score 10):

This should work:

```
parseInt($("h1").css("font-size"))
```

Comment: Be careful with `parseInt`, it's Octal by design. Always use [`parseInt(..., 10)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for decimal values

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using this method?

```
var size = $(element).css('font-size');
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
function em(input) {
 var emSize = parseFloat($("h1").css("font-size"));
 return (emSize * input);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use `css()` to get the font-size... this gives the size in px... so divide it by 16 should give you the value in `em`.
try this

```
 var sizeinem=parseFloat($('h1').css('font-size')) / 16;
 alert(sizeinem);
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/XSjDJ/)

Comment: Please note the requirements for the question are to get font size in px, not em.  So `css('font-size')` is sufficient.

Comment: Why would you think dividing by 16 would give you the font-size in em? This is only correct if the font-size for your document happens to be 16px, but otherwise this will not be correct!