# Android / iOS device font-size

Tags: cordova

I'm starting to work on a application using Cordova and am wondering if there is a way to access the font / text size setting of a device on Android / iOS?

Comment: The same as web, you can get pixel size with jQuery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154601/detect-font-size-in-pixels-using-jquery

Comment: @malcubierre so if the user goes into (Android) Settings > Display > Font size and changes the value there, the webview inside cordova will pick up on that?

Comment: @Wayferer Native font size will not be picked up by the webview.

Comment: @cforcloud thank you. Are you aware of any plugins or any way of doing so?

Comment: I have checked that changes in settings also are changing  $("#id").css('font-size') pixels

Comment: @malcubierre I have just tested this using `getComputedStyle(document.querySelector('body')).getPropertyValue('font-size')` and regardless of what I set in the settings it still returned 16px. Can you explain what you did differently?

Comment: I rendered a html example in a kitkat Android. I debugged with Chrome inspect for Android. I chose a text with an ID and checked before and after setting changes

Comment: @malcubierre thank you for your help. Can you say if you used the emulator or an actual device?